# Django error "invalid literal for int()" when attempting to use pk_url_kwarg

Tags: django

I'm having trouble understanding why this won't work and what is causing this error. I just want to put the program code into the URL and have it display the detail page. It works fine with the primary key but can't figure it out using the kwarg. What am I doing wrong?

My **views.py**

```
class ProgramDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Program
    template_name = 'submissions/program_details.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'program_code'
```

My **urls.py**

```
path('<program_code>/', ProgramDetailView.as_view(), name='program-detail'),
```

My **models.py**

```
class Program(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    program_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    program_board = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    monthly_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_code
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T0001'
```

Comment: Well `program_code`, is expected to be a *primary key*, but apparently your primary key is an integer.

Comment: Is there a way to change it to expect a string instead of integer?

Comment: Well you can change the primary key (by setting the `program_code=models.CharField(max_length=5, pk=True)`). But you probably want to filter on another column.

Comment: I did program_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary_key=True) and it worked, thanks!